# Ambiguous installation instructions for Realm iOS

Tags: ios, realm

Steps 3 and 4 say:

> 3. In your unit test target’s “Build Settings”, add the parent path to
>      RealmSwift.framework in the “Framework Search Paths” section.
> 4. If using
>      Realm in an iOS, tvOS or watchOS project, create a new “Run Script
>      Phase” in your app’s target’s “Build Phases” and paste the following
>      snippet in the script text field:
>
>    bash "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH}/Realm.framework/strip-frameworks.sh"
>
>    This step is required to work around an App Store submission bug when
>      archiving universal binaries.

But it doesn't say where the unit test target's "Build Settings" or app's target's "Build Phases" are. Where are these things?

Comment: It's in your app target in your `.xcodeproj`, there is a tab called `build phase`

Comment: what does app target mean, target for what? i clicked on the main project folder and went to the "Build Phases" tab and didn't see anything that said "Run Script Phase"

Comment: that place is your app target, see on the left tab its on the `target`, and you have to press the `+` button, and `add run script`

Answer (score 1):

The Build Settings and Build Phases panes are panels in Xcode which have various settings and whatnot that you can customize to your needs.

To follow the instructions that Realm provided, you can navigate to "Test" however this will change to what your project is called.

[image: Project Name]

And then Build Settings and Build phases are available around the middle of your screen at the top in Xcode. See the following screenshot:

[image: Build Settings and Build Phases panes]

From there you can open up Build Phases and click the plus (+) on the left hand side to create a "New Run Script Phase."

And from there, all what's left is filling in the information we supply in the documentation to create the run script phase.

I hope this helps. Cheers!

Comment: Did this answer your question @shoe? Please mark my answer as the approved/correct answer if you are satisfied with the response you received. If not, please let me know how if there's anything else I can help with.